# how to prove an identity related to $\int_0^\infty\sin(x^{1+a})dx$?

Tags: calculus, analysis, trigonometry, fresnel-integrals

i have made some experiments in maple evaluating the integral $$\int_0^\infty\sin(x^{1+a})dx$$
and the computer give me the following result

$$\int_0^\infty\sin(x^{1+a})dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}2^{\frac{2}{2+2a}}\Gamma(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2+2a})}{(2+2a)\Gamma(1-\frac{1}{2+2a})}$$

and i realy want to know how can i prove that. i hope some of you can help me.
An interesting thing is that de right side converges to $1$ when $a$ goes to $0$.

Comment: At the risk of being pedantic, the r.h.s. going to 1 as $a$ goes to 0 does not imply $\int_0^\infty\sin(x)dx=1$.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably $a > 0$.  The change of variable $t = x^{1+a}$ leads to
$$ \dfrac{1}{1+a} \int_0^\infty \sin(t)\; t^{-a/(1+a)}\ dt$$

Now let $a/(1+a) = b$, and note that $0 < b < 1$.  Now for $\rm{Re}(r) > 0$

$$ \int_0^\infty  e^{-r t}\ t^{-b}\ dt = r^{b-1} \Gamma(1-b)$$
Taking the limit as $r \to  i$ (and not worrying about convergence)
we get 
$$ \int_0^\infty e^{ -i t} t^{-b}\ dt = (i)^{b-1} \Gamma(1-b)
= e^{i\pi (b-1)/2} \Gamma(1-b)$$ 
and taking $-$ the imaginary part of this
$$ \int_{0}^\infty \sin(t) t^{-b}\ dt = - \sin(\pi (b-1)/2) \Gamma(1-b) $$
Now you want to apply some Gamma function identities...